# Is there an online and/or English-language version of the "Jiǔmíngjì" 酒名記?

Tags: history, classification

I was reading Peter Kupfer's scholarly piece [*Amber Shine and Black Dragon Pearls: The History of Chinese Wine Culture*](http://sino-platonic.org/complete/spp278_chinese_wine_culture_history.pdf) (June 2018). During the Song Dynasty (960–1279), it says,

> large amounts of surplus crops provided plenty of raw material for the production of a broad variety of alcohol beverages. These activities generated an impressive collection of encyclopedic works about *jiu*, for example *Jiumingji* (Catalogue of names of alcoholic drinks) listing altogether 223 different kinds, with sometimes curious names and ingredients (like a drink called "White Lamb" fermented with lamb meat broth).

Google informs me that the *Jiǔmíngjì* 酒名記 "Wine name catalogue" was written by Zhāng Néngchén 張能臣 (see [Japanese-language catalog entry here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1xtKAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22%E9%85%92%E5%90%8D%E8%A8%98%22+%22%E5%BC%B5%E8%83%BD%E8%87%A3%22&pg=PP576)), but that's about it.

I'd be interested to read some of these curiously named and composed drinks. Has the *Jiǔmíngjì* ever been translated into English? Has a Chinese version ever been digitized?

Comment: This question seems to fit more on the literature and/or language stack exchange...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a copy at Harvard uploaded here: https://curiosity.lib.harvard.edu/chinese-rare-books/catalog/49-990067588510203941

I doubt this has been translated, but if you have a native speaker with strong historical Chinese understanding (probably just a strong student), you can probably get this project underway :)